# vue component compilation issue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm pretty new to Vue.js so bear with me. I'm working on a project where I created two new vue components, one is a tab/toggle element, the other is a cookie banner. However, when both are added to the page the cookie banner does not compile. The HTML is rendered but it still contains all the vue syntax in its uncompiled form. Does anyone see where the conflict is occurring between these two components? I don't see any errors in the console so I'm at a loss on how to begin debugging.

Component 1:

```
(function () {

    var _instance = new Vue({
        el: "#multiTrackSwiper",
        data: {
            tabs: {}
        },
        methods: {
            checkActiveTab: function (index) {
                if (this.tabs['active']) {
                    return this.tabs['active'] === index;
                } else {
                    return index === "0";
                }
            },
            handlerActiveTab: function (index) {
                Vue.set(this.tabs, 'active', index);
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

```
@using Sitecore.Feature.Media.Models.Components
@model List<ITrackWithCarousel>


@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    if (Model.Count == 1)
    {
        <div class="c-product-details__track">
            @Html.Partial("TrackWithCarousel", Model[0])
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        var index = 0;
        <div id="multiTrackSwiper" class="multi-track-swiper" vue-instance v-cloak>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                @foreach (var track in Model)
                {
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <button id="tab_@track.Name.Replace(" ","_")" data-bs-toggle="tab" class="nav-link"
                                v-bind:class="{ 'active':checkActiveTab('@index') }"
                                v-on:click="handlerActiveTab('@index')">
                            @track.DisplayName
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    index++;
                }
            </ul>
            @{ index = 0; }
            @foreach (var track in Model)
            {
                <div class="c-product-details__track c-product-details__multitrack" aria-labelledby="tab_@track.Name.Replace(" ","_")"
                     v-bind:class="{ 'active':checkActiveTab('@index') }">
                    @Html.Partial("TrackWithCarousel", track)
                </div>
                index++;
            }
        </div>
    }
}
```

Component 2:

```
(function () {

    var _instance = new Vue({
        el: "#cookie-banner",
        data: {
            cookieSaved: null
        },
        methods: {
            saveSessionCookie: function () {
                var expiry = (new Date(Date.now() + 600 * 1000)).toUTCString(); // 3 days 259200
                document.cookie = "cookie-banner-closed=true; expires=" + expiry + ";path=/;"
                this.cookieSaved = true;
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            if (document.cookie.includes('cookie-banner-closed')) {
                this.cookieSaved = true;
            } else {
                this.cookieSaved = null;
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

```
<div id="cookie-banner" vue-instance v-cloak>
    <div class="cookie-disclaimer" v-if="!cookieSaved">
        <div id="cookie-notice">
            <div class="cookie-inner-module h-spacing">
                This website uses cookies. We do this to better understand how visitors use our site and to offer you a more personal experience. We share information about your use of our site with social media and analytics partners in accordance with our Privacy Notice</a>. 
                <i class="fas fa-times" v-on:click="saveSessionCookie"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried switching both vue components into vue instances instead but that doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Which version of Vue are you using? And what build tool are you using?

Comment: Have you got any error in the console?

Answer (score 0):

**The HTML is rendered but it still contains all the vue syntax in its uncompiled form.**

I don't think that you are using Vue format/syntax. So it will render what you are typed inside html.